# How to animate the polyline on Google Map in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

`[image]

I need the exact animation

```
_renderMap() {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _animation!,
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
          return FutureBuilder<Set<Marker>>(
            future: _getTowerMarkers(),
            initialData: const <Marker>{},
            builder: (context, snapshot) => SizedBox(
              height: 200,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: GoogleMap(
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  zoomControlsEnabled: true,
                  initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(
                          _attendanceViewModel.coordinatesList![0].latitude!,
                          _attendanceViewModel.coordinatesList![0].longitude!),
                      zoom: 9.0),
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    _controller.complete(controller);
                  },
                  markers: snapshot.data!,
                  polylines: {
                    Polyline(
                        polylineId: PolylineId("route"),
                        points: latLen,
                        width: 5,
                        patterns: [PatternItem.dot, PatternItem.dot],
                        startCap: Cap.roundCap,
                        endCap: Cap.roundCap,
                        color: AppColors.green)
                  }),
            ),
          );
        });
  }`
```